# getDerivedStateFromProps is not called

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-16

I use **React 16.3.1** and **next.js**.
And I put **getDerivedStateFromProps** inside the class extending **PureComponent**.

Here is the code:

> Header.js

```
import { PureComponent } from 'react'
...

export default class Header extends PureComponent {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.colorAnimationProps = {
      animationDuration: '0.4s',
      animationFillMode: 'forwards'
    }

    this.colorAnimationStyle = {
      toColor: {
        animationName: 'toColor',
        ...this.colorAnimationProps
      },
      toTransparent: {
        animationName: 'toTransparent',
        ...this.colorAnimationProps
      }
    }

    this.state = {
      colorAnimation: {},
      headerModal: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    if (this.props.isColor) {
      this.setState({colorAnimation: this.colorAnimationStyle.toColor})
    }
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps (nextProps, prevState) {
    console.log('should go here')
    if (nextProps.isColor) {
      return {colorAnimation: this.colorAnimationStyle.toColor}
    }
    return {colorAnimation: this.colorAnimationStyle.toTransparent}
  }

  render () {
    ...
  }
}
```

And here is the parent that modifies the prop:

> index.js

```
import { PureComponent } from 'react'

...
import Header from '../components/Header'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import { withReduxSaga } from '../redux/store'

class Index extends PureComponent {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      isHeaderColor: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    if (window.pageYOffset > 50) {
      this.setState({isHeaderColor: true})
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
      if (window.pageYOffset > 50) {
        this.setState({isHeaderColor: true})
      } else {
        this.setState({isHeaderColor: false})
      }
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Layout url={this.props.url}>
        <Header isColor={this.state.isHeaderColor} />
        ...
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}

export default withReduxSaga(Index)
```

My problem is: getDerivedStateFromProps is not called when the prop changes. At least, it should do console.log, but it doesn't.

Can anybody here help me?

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: @TheReason I'm sorry, I forgot to put the code. I just updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: Where your `props` come from?

Comment: @TheReason The props come from the parent, index.js. I just updated my question again. And again, thank you.

Comment: which version of nextjs you use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see that support for this hook [was patched in version - 6.0.0-canary.2 of next.JS](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/releases/tag/6.0.0-canary.2). So I'm guessing you use an older version.

Answer (score 38):

make sure you have the right versions of both `react` **and** `react-dom` in your `package.json`:

```
"react": "^16.3.1",
"react-dom": "^16.3.1"
```

Comment: This worked for me-- I had only upgraded `react` to `16.3.2`. `react-dom` was still at `16.2.0`