# getDerivedStateFromProps not called in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use the new [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) lifecycle method in my React Native component but the method never gets called. I've tried looking it up but found [no issues](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=getDerivedStateFromProps) in the react-native repo. No results on StackOverflow or Google either.

What I did find are a [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/8abmdl/getderivedstatefromprops_not_working/) and a [StackOverflow issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50010498/2634633) which both cite updating `react-dom` as a solution, which would not work in this case since there's no dom in React Native.

**Can anyone confirm if this method is supposed to work in React Native?** If it can be used, any help with solving this issue will be much appreciated.

Below is a simplified version of my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { Auth } from '../redux';
import ChillaAPI from '../api';

const withUserData = WrappedComponent => {
  class UserDataLoader extends React.Component {

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {

      console.log('getDerivedStateFromProps');

      if (props.uid !== state.uid) {
        return {
          uid: props.uid,
        };
      }

      return state;
    }

    state = { uid: null };

    render() {
      console.log({ propsUid: this.props.uid });
      console.log({ stateUid: this.state.uid });
      return <WrappedComponent />;
    }
  }

  UserDataLoader.propTypes = {
    uid: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  };

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(UserDataLoader);

};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    uid: Auth.selectors.getUid(state),
  };
}

export default withUserData;
```

The log output from the component is as follows:

```
{ propsUid: null }
{ stateUid: null }
{ propsUid: 'jW78ej3JDgPpheadAlcrkG8UIZB2' }
{ stateUid: null }
```

Here is my package.json for good measure:

```
{
  "name": "Chilla",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "start:reset": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start --reset-cache",
    "watch:lint": "node node_modules/eslint-watch/bin/esw -w",
    "test": "jest",
    "precommit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": [
      "node_modules/.bin/prettier --single-quote --trailing-comma es5 --write",
      "eslint",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "firebase": "^4.13.1",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "lint-staged": "^7.0.4",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.52.2",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.7",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.11",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "recompose": "^0.27.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.2.1",
    "eslint-watch": "^3.1.4",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "prettier": "^1.12.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that the static function getDerivedStateFromProps() works in react-native as expected, I am using it since I refactored my code after the react v16.3 update. I can't really see why it's not working for you. I assume you double checked the spelling in your editor and confirmed that react v16.3.1 really is installed and compiled? If you are using a simulator you can also try deleting the app and do a re-install. Helped my on several occasions at least ...

Comment: @dentemm I did all that. Now that I think of it, it's probably my version of `react-native`, I'm on v0.52.2. Could you confirm you're using at least v0.55.0?

Answer (score 2):

Updating to `react-native@0.55.3` solved this issue